# Risks of running code after action returned ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, shared-hosting

I'm running an MVC 3 application on a shared hosting and there are a few pages which require a lot of processing that shouldn't keep the user waiting. (Examples: sending a few hundred mails with attachments, creating several thousand records in a database.)

Now I'm not asking how to achieve this, because I know how, what I would like to know is. Is there a risk of my application stopping if it's performing an operation for say... 60 seconds?

If so, what can you do to prevent it (knowing that the application cannot run in full trust)?

Comment: how about using a Queue<> mechanism, for the emails and sending them on a different time then when the page was called ?

Comment: If the application shuts down, the queue is lost, don't think that'll work :S.

Comment: Functionality as you describe should really be run out of process in a Windows service for durability, performance, scalability, etc.

Comment: @TimMedora That's impossible due to it being a shared-hosting.

Comment: I know, that's why I didn't post as an answer. But relying on a long running action to successfully complete in a web process is usually a shaky proposition.

Comment: @TimMedora I know, but workaround (like relying on javascript to keep on polling a webserver for say every 10 mails) is even more unreliable.

Comment: You can use external Queue, like Amazon SQS service to collect jobs. Than you need to call some service which will check queue every 5 minutes and do what is in it.

Comment: @Aidiakapi - to answer your original question, I have used the thread pool inside a web process to execute long-running actions and they never stopped responding (of course they can be terminated if the app pool recycles).

Comment: @TimMedora And that's the problem, how to avoid them from dying due to recycles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used Task for this, something like

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => this.SendRequestApprovedNotification(requestId, 
    userName, 
    comments));
```

One problem I ran into was I was naively passing the request object through to the task. Don't do this, instead copy out the bits you need and pass those down, as, by the time you could to use the request object the pipeline may have disposed it.

Comment: Good point about the disposed thing, I was already aware of this though. Yet this still has the same problem. The recycling.

Comment: Well it won't recycle due to inactivity whilst tasks are running. If it recycles, then either there's been a reboot, or your app crashed. So you could have a database table somewhere which you could poll on startup and figure out what tasks didn't get run. A poor man's message queue :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on shared hosting, you might wanna check out [HostingEnvironment.IncreaseBusyCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.incrementbusycount.aspx) and [DecreaseBusyCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.decrementbusycount.aspx).

You might also wanna take a look at [HostingEnvironment.RegisterObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.registerobject.aspx), which would give you a chance to cancel whatever's going on before the application stops.

Having said that, I haven't tried any of these, and they may not be particularly reliable. This [article](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx) is pretty relevant on why it's not a great idea to do this from within the site, but I get that you're stuck in that regard.

Comment: This DOES actually work, the problem is that since I'm in a shared hosting I don't run in full trust. This is as close as I've gotten to a solution too.

Answer (score 0):

You can control duration of request execution from web.config:

```
  <location path="Controller/ProcessFile">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="900" />
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

executionTimeout - allowed time in seconds

However, I am using it on dedicated server, not shared hosting.

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with the request length. Since this should happen outside of the request.